# Php mysql bad query when displays on a table

Tags: mysql

there's my code that select 5 databases and display in a table, but the where statement not work

The where is ignored by the query.

```
SELECT *
FROM events
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM eventstwo
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM eventsthree
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM eventsfour
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM eventsfive where atender='$obj'
```

Comment: "not work" is a completely unhelpful description. What's it supposed to do? What's it actually do?

Comment: The query is ignoring the where in the statement.

Comment: On where not work, and with only where is the same problem

Comment: Do you have a column named as "atender" and any row in the column has "$obj" as data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you want the `WHERE` criteria to apply to *every* subquery in the union.  If you want that, you'll have to add a `WHERE` clause to each subquery.  But, if you really do want to use a single `WHERE` clause, you can wrap your union query and then subquery it:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT * FROM events
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM eventstwo
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM eventsthree
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM eventsfour
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM eventsfive
) t
WHERE atender = '$obj';
```

Side note: Please use prepared statements in your PHP code wherever possible.

Comment: Yep and now i use prepared statements but im new with the unions, thank you for the help tim.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM
              ( SELECT *
                FROM events
                UNION ALL
                SELECT * FROM eventstwo
                UNION ALL
                SELECT * FROM eventsthree
                UNION ALL
                SELECT * FROM eventsfour
                UNION ALL
                SELECT * FROM eventsfive)
                  AS derived
WHERE atender='$obj'
```